# Where is located Daihatsu Materia VIN code?

Tags: daihatsu

I am looking for the Daihatsu Materia VIN code on the car. I cannot look at papers right now. I had a look:

- under the front window
- under both front seeds
- an all doors, when open
- in the engine area
- around the wheel
- under the front part of the vehicle

and haven't found it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicles Maintenance & Repair! Depending on the year of the vehicle, the VIN could be located in different positions on the vehicle. Could you please provide that?

Comment: The VIN can often be found on the lower-left corner of the dashboard, in front of the steering wheel. You can read the number by looking through the windshield on the driver's side of the vehicle. The VIN may also appear in a number of other locations: Front of the engine block.

Comment: It appears most Daihatsus put the VIN in multiple locations, with the very common place of at the cowl (metal area below the windshield at the back of the engine compartment). A lot of them have it stamped on the  metal on the right side (as you're sitting in the car). It would have a six pointed asterisk at the front and end of the VIN. There may also be a VIN plate on the left side, which would have more information on it. [This image may help](https://www.vinnumberlocation.com/uploads/1/3/9/9/1399825/8141538_orig.jpg). Putting this as a comment, because I really don't know for sure.